How to parse in search param that is multi valued into useNavigate?
I have data as follows:
const basket = {
  type: 'fruits',
  filter: 'sour',
  filter: 'sweet,
}

I am using React-Router useNavigate() to navigate to another webpage after selecting the column filters. I will need the search parameters to be populated as the query string like this:
"https://www.abcmart.com?type=fruits&filter=sour&filter=sweet".
I tried to parse in the filters to the search param of useNavigate() but it keeps converting the multi-valued search param 'fruits' (string[]) to comma separator, making my query string look like this instead - "type=fruit&filter=sour,sweet" instead of using ampersand separator e.g. "filter=sour&filter=sweet".
In other words, for the single value param (string), it appends ampersand but when joined by an array, it converts to comma. I tried many methods such as conversion and replace but it didnt work.
Original code:
basket = {
  type: 'fruits',
  filter: ['sour, sweet'],
}
UseNavigate({
  to: 'abcmart',
  search: {
    basket,
  }
)

What can I do so that useNavigate can convert array into one separated by ampersand?
Tried converting the string[], and replace, but useNavigate still converts string[] to separate by comma. I even tried to generate a string[] using useSearchParam from React-Router but it does not allow me to declare same filter name twice.

basket.filter is an array, but the value is the string literal "sour, sweet", so if you want separate filter search param values you'll need to do a bit of string manipulation first.


const basket = {
  type: "fruits",
  filter: ["sour, sweet"],
};

const params = new URLSearchParams();

// set the type parameter
params.set("type", basket.type);

// iterate the filter array, string split & iterate each entry
// and append a new filter parameter
basket.filter.forEach((filterItem) =>
  filterItem.split(", ").forEach((item) => params.append("filter", item))
);

console.log(params.toString()); // "type=fruits&filter=sour&filter=sweet"



const navigate = useNavigate();

...

const handler = () => {
  const params = new URLSearchParams();

  params.set("type", basket.type);
  basket.filter.forEach((filterItem) =>
    filterItem.split(", ").forEach((item) => params.append("filter", item))
  );

  // React-Router navigate function
  navigate(
    {
      pathname: "abcmart",
      search: params.toString(),
    },
    { replace: true }
  );

  // Tanstack Router navigate function
  navigate({
    to: "abcmart",
    search: params.toString(),
    replace: true,
  });
};


Thanks! But it doesn't work... The result query string became very weird... `0=t&1=y&2=p&3=e&4=f&5=r&6=u&7=i&8=t&9=s&....' if you notice the letters, they seem to follow type=fruits but somehow they are split into this string... why did this happen?

@August Odd, this code worked just I had expected in a sandbox and also in the stack snippet I provided. It looks like you might've incorrectly string split the type parameter which didn't need any special handling, or maybe you did some odd spread syntax somewhere?

@August Here's a running sandbox demo.

The property name inside my navigate() looks a bit different from yours... when I tried to use pathname, it threw error saying it does not exist in type. I have been using this code below but it resulted in the weird query string 0=t&1=y&2=p&3=e&4=f&5=r&6=u&7=i&8=t&9=s&....:
navigate(
{
to: '/abcmart',
params: {
basketId,
}
},
search: params.toString(),
replace: true,
});

@August Are you using an older version of React-Router? Or are you using v6 and maybe have an old v5 typescript dependency still installed? The search property is the only valid property you listed in your navigate call. Can you share a sandbox of your code?

Actually I am not using react-router-dom. I'm using Tanstack router 1.26.1 and typescript 5.3.3. Is the Tanstack router able to support this? As far as possible, tanstack router is to be used.

@August Why did you tag your post with [tag:react-router] then? With regards to your question, I have no idea, I typically avoid tanstack products, but my guess is that it can support it since there's no 3rd-party library dependency on working with URLSearchParams objects and strings in Javascript, e.g. the stack snippet included in my answer. Think you could create a running Codesandbox demo of your code we could inspect live?

`
import { useNavigate } from '@tanstack/react-router';
basket = {
type: 'fruits',
filter: ['sour, sweet'],
}
useNavigate({
to: 'abcmart',
search: {
type=type,
filter=filter,
}
)
`

for some reason, i cant get the sandbox working

do you have example where you use tanstack-router?

@August It should be about as trivial as the // Tanstack Router navigate function code in my snippet. I can see what I can whip up. It might take some time though. I'll report back to you.
